# Google is showing cached results for a website, and I cannot view the results with any cache

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I tried accessing the results by typing `cache:(website)` in Chrome, didn't work. Tried typing `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:(website)`. Didn't work. Wayback machine has the site archived, but only the front page. Also, Bing can find other topics and such on the website, and so can the mobile Google search. I just can't access the cached pages of the site at all, but Google and Bing are crawling the site and showing search results. Does anyone know why?

Comment: It would be much easier to accurately answer this question if you said what "website" is. For example, search engines can index websites even if they are robots-excluded. That would mean no caching and no Wayback, which appears to fit what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

The searched website cached content will be available in the drop down option near to the search link available as shown in the image below. Please check whether the cached content is showing for the website.

click the [image]